# Regenerating access keys in Azure by REST API

Tags: azure

For Azure there is an [API Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/regeneratekey) that allows to regenerate key. 
The endpoint looks like

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/regenerateKey?api-version=2017-06-01
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal) states

> When you have code that needs to access or modify resources, you must set up an Azure Active Directory (AD) application.

However, when I use it (i.e. create POST request) I'm getting error `Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing.` I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal) and I did all the steps except **Assign application to role** What role should I select to be able to regenerate password? How do I do that? Am I getting this correct?

Comment: You can try with in-built `Contributor` or `Storage Account Contributor` role.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal or search for `Azure Portal Role Based Access Control`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [Storage Account Key Operator Service Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-account-key-operator-service-role).

The Storage Account Key Operators are allowed to **list and regenerate keys on Storage Account**.

**Storage Account Contributor**: Lets you manage storage accounts, but not access to them.

**Contributor**:Lets you manage everything except access to resources.

If you have some more action to operate, you could use more powerful roles, but if you only want to regenerate key, I suggest that you could use Storage Account Key Operator Service Role.

Comment: Could you point me to documentation with examples on how to set up this?

Comment: Here is an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-security-guide) about how to secure your storage account with Role-Based Access Control. Its steps are almost similar with this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal), you could change resource group to your storage account.